# GICS to NAICS crosswalk

Tags: mapping, classification, crosswalk

For the last two weeks I have been in search of a mapping/crosswalk between Global Industry Classification Standard (GICS) and North American Industry Classification Standard (NAICS) and have found little luck.

NAICS: https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/sssd/naics/naicsrch?chart=2017

GICS: https://www.msci.com/gics

This is something I feel like should exists as there is plenty of GICS/NAICS classified data researchers would like to relate.

Does anyone know of such a mapping/crosswalk or a reason why this could never be done?

Comment: Figured it out, emailed S&P and they provided a mapping.

Comment: Hi! I also emailed S&P and they told me that they were not able to find the perfect mapping from GICS to NAICS. Can you share the solution for me? Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to upload this anywhere? or share the email of S&P anyone

Answer (score 2):

GICS values are actually market data sold by Standard and Poors.  Since S&P created and owns the mapping, you have to pay for the information.  Many investment banks provide the GICS data but they have a license from S&P.  That's why there isn't a public utility to lookup/map to other codes.